# How to publish message in Google Pub/Sub from Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I wrote a function that receive a http request and send a e-mail. But, I would like receive a http request and send a pub message. The problem is that the documentation is not clear. How I do that?

This is my actual code.

```
exports.weeklyEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
const email = '****@gmail.com'

console.log('Sending e-mail')

const mailOptions = {
    to: email,
    from: '****@alunos.utfpr.edu.br',
    subject: 'Teste',
    text: 'Conteudo do email '
}   

mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(
    () => {         
        res.send('Email sent')
    }
).catch(error => {
    res.send(error)
})
})
```

Answer (score 15):

As I understand, you wish to send a message to Pub/Sub from your Firebase Cloud Functions implementation.

You can easily use the [Node.js Pub/Sub client library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.16.x/), with already defined functionalities, like [publish](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.16.x/v1.PublisherClient#publish).

Or, if you prefer, you can build your own *client*, directly calling the [REST API for Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/). There's also a [RPC reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/) if it suits your needs better.

---

You won't need

> information like host, port, id, passwd of broker

as the mentioned client, or your REST API requests will require [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) 
.

Comment: Do you know if I can use this in iOS app without Apple Push Notifications Service?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of Apple Push Notifications Service. Given that Google's Pub/Sub can be implemented via the [APIs Services](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview), it should be independent of the platform, programming language... i.e. as long as an HTTP client can be implemented to perform requests to the REST API endpoints.

I don't know if it's relevant, or a good analogy, but [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) works with iOS as well... so it might be the same for Cloud Pub/Sub

Comment: your comment might worth a new SO post as it will treat a specifically different topic. From "how to publish in Pub/Sub from Firebase Cloud Function" to "how to integrate Apple Push Notifications Service with .... " (a guess)

Comment: Speaking of authentication - how to authenticate a Pub/Sub client library when it is used in a Fireabse Cloud Function? I tried to create a simple function and I receive a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error when the function attempts to publish a message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import pub-sub library `const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')`, initiate client, and publish messages.
Docs:

- https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish-messages-to-a-topic
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

---

However, One more way is to trigger background function on [firestore writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).

whenever you create a doc in a collection (*pubsub*), your bg function will get invoked on the doc write:

```js
exports.myTriggerFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('pubsub/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

Also, it's just not limited to `onCreate`:

```
Event Type  Trigger
onCreate    Triggered when a document is written to for the first time.
onUpdate    Triggered when a document already exists and has any value changed.
onDelete    Triggered when a document with data is deleted.
onWrite     Triggered when onCreate, onUpdate or onDelete is triggered.
```